# How to inset Text at the top left corner in Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d

So i have the following codes:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.5]
  }, Axes -> False, Boxed -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/5}, 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed, Thick], 
 PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 40}, {-4, 4}}, ImageSize -> {900, 600},
 Epilog -> Inset[
   Text[Style["Title", FontSize -> 40, 
     FontFamily -> "Lucida Calligraphy"]], {Left, Top}, {Left, Top}]
 ]
```

the output is:[image]

The "title" is not placed at the top left corner on the image, i want it to be at the corner of the orange box, pls help.

Comment: Try something like `Labeled[(* stuff *), Style["Title", FontSize -> 40, FontFamily -> "Lucida Calligraphy"], {{Top, Left}}]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting J.M.'s comment as an answer:

```
Labeled[
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.5]}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> True, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/5}, 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed, Thick], 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 40}, {-4, 4}}, ImageSize -> {900, 600}
  ],
 Style["Title", FontSize -> 40, FontFamily -> "Lucida Calligraphy"],
 {{Top, Left}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks, but would you pls explain why Labeled[] works, but inset[] doesn't? when i used inset[], the tile constantly adjusts its position, why does that happen?

Comment: @DORA I think it's because you need to set the `PlotRange` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Panel[obj, title]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Panel.html) which, by default, places *title* on the top left:

```
label = Style["Title", FontSize -> 40, FontFamily -> "Lucida Calligraphy"];

graphics = Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.5]}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> True, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/5}, 
   BoxStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed, Thick], 
   PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 40}, {-4, 4}}, 
   ImageSize -> {500, 400}];

Panel[graphics, label]
```

[image]

You can remove the frame using the option `Appearance -> "Frameless"`:

```
Panel[graphics, label, Appearance -> "Frameless", Background -> White]
```

[image]

We get the same picture using

```
Panel[graphics, "Title",
 Appearance -> "Frameless", Background -> White, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 40, FontFamily -> "Lucida Calligraphy"}]
```